# $scope value in controller is not identified by AngularJS directive

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, requirejs, angular-amd, dropzone

I am trying to use Dropzone module for AngularJs and I have problem applying it to my own code. The module has been defined **[here](https://github.com/Igosuki/angular-dropzone)** but there is no documentation on its usage. Here is what I am doing:

**Step 1: Injecting ngDropzone to my module:**

```
define([
  'angular',
  './services/index',
  './controllers/index',
  'angular-ui-router',
  'angular-animate',
  'Angular-Dropzone
  ], function (angular, services, controllers) {
     'use strict';

     var app = angular.module('appName', ['ui.router', 'ngAnimate', 'ngDropzone']);

     return app;
  });
```

**Step 2: Seting dropzoneConfig in controller scope**

```
define([
  'angular',
  '../module',
], function (angular, controllers) {
'use strict';

return {
    name: "uploadcontroller",
    controller: ['$scope', '$interval', '$rootScope',
        function ($scope, $interval, $rootScope) {

            $scope.dropzoneConfig = {
                'options': {
                    'url': '/fileupload'
                }
            };
        }
    ]
};
});
```

**Step 3: Inserting directive to html**

```
<ng-dropzone></ng-dropzone>
```

After running my app I receive the following error:

```
Error: No URL provided.
```

Comment: I dont think that using unknown module without documentation is good idea.

Comment: Use this instead: https://github.com/thatisuday/ng-dropzone Detailed documentation is given, fulfilling same requirement